# What's the distinction between an "entity" and a "game object"?

Tags: naming-conventions, game-engine, naming

I'm working on a 3D engine API here (a rendering engine, not a game engine as such) and trying to get the class names right.

In my system, I have a soup of components such as "camera", "transform", "lights", "material" etc, including another component type which I've called "object".

Each "object" has one link to each of the other component types, ie. a link to a "camera", a link to a "material", and so on.

Pretty standard stuff.

My question is - should that be called "object" or "entity", or something else?

Can anyone perhaps point me to canonical literature on these concepts? Seems to be a matter of personal taste for many people, but for max comprehension of the docs I'd like to get this subtlety nailed down.

Comment: I do not think that there is THE literature in this area that does not represent the personal taste of its author. The question is what your "object" really is and why it contains a link to these components - i would expect some form of inheritance here. If these objects are part of a scene graph, maybe "node" is right to underline this. If they are purely programming  "helpers" to group these components into one list "object" or something else related to programming is better. "Entity" as an abstract "thing that exists" may not be the case as "material" is more like an attribute of an entity.

Comment: Aha right - so "object" would imply OOP. A "material" could be seen as an "aspect" or attribute of an "entity". Guess I just want to get a sense of what the implications in people's minds, this helps.

Comment: "Object" would not strictly imply oop as it could also refer to a real world object - but i think in this case most people think of oop if they hear it. Again, with "aspect" or "attribute" the context matters. While aspect seems more colloquial or abstract to me, attribute is something heard of in the context of describing "materials" etc. It all depends on the setting you think in. If it comes to shaders some people might take "attribute" as a special shader variable in GLSL, so if you want strong focus on GLSL you might want something else, but otherwise its ok i think.

Comment: I would say: Material could be seen as property of an Entity. (but this is not true).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have seen few webgl javascript engines. Terminology was different for each.

> Distinction between an “entity” and a “game object”?

Usually object is something you can perceive with vision and/or touch. While entity might be perceived only with sixth sense or not at all (two cameras in scene cant perceive each other). Each object is entity, but not each entity is represented with object.

**In programming,** 
Camera, lights, models, scene, all of them need position, rotation and scale. Also a lot of things are dependent so here comes another important word: Node.

In OOP hierarchy Node is the first. It has exactly one parent, except first node which has none, and zero or more children.
Entity extends Node. It has position, rotation, scale + parent, children. Each transformation will impact all children. 
Object extends Entity. Object might have additional various properties like set of meshes, (Each Object is composed from one or more meshes, each mesh has material).

**Tips:**

Sometimes it is useless to have 3 different objects in OOP hierarchy. Most of engines merge them to single object or two and different components might exclude properties in constructor. For example global light doesnt need position, rotation or scale. Directional light doesnt need position and scale, but needs rotation. But extending whole OOP hierarchy only because of two components doesnt worth.

In playcanvas its name is Entity. In threejs its name is Object3D. Name might be also GraphNode or Node, as it is in cocos2d (which is 2d engine).

I dont have any literature, but i agree with Thomas in this: try to avoid words like Object, Node, because it is confusing. I think the best name to merge this together is Entity, but it has nothing to do with what is more or less, or description of the word itself. The most important thing is, what do you and others find as confusing.

Comment: BTW this part is like superimportant "Each Object is composed from one or more meshes, each mesh has material", because if you ever work with blender or other studio, you should know exported model is set of meshes hierarchy and sometimes even more. You will have to choose what kinds of models can your engine work with (is compatible).

Comment: In general in OOP, each object (instance of a class) can have multiple parents via multiple inheritance, so node is not good here because of OOP. However i do agree node is good because it looks like you are building a scene graph and "connection points" in graph theory are called nodes. Also, in a scene graph, each node should have one parent only since its position must be pinned by the series of transformations up to the root. Again, speaking in graph terms a node can have multiple parents = inward edges in general.